# Функция filter, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, filter

Подскажите пожалуйста, в подсказке PyCharm по функции filter выдает следующую информацию:

[image: Filter]

Я не понимаю формат записи в 3-ей и 4-ой строках, а именно:
Что означают (_Т) в скобках?
Почему у function и iterable впереди подчеркивания?
Что означает эта стрелка -> Any?

Comment: Это указание типов в случае если используется типизация

Comment: `->` означает, что функция возвращает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае скорее всего у вам показана типизация.
Например функцию можно записать как:

```py
def myfunc(a):
    return a
# или 
def myfunc (a: str) -> str:
    return a
```

В данном случае `a` это строка и функция возвращает `-> str` тоже строку.

По факту никаких ограничений на передаваемые параметры нет, но многие IDE могут подсказать если передаете что-то не то.